# How to echo out a menu built using bs4navwalker?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I want to get a `menu` created in WP and echo it out on the page, but it doesn't seem to pull the menu items?

**footer-nav.php:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-faded">

    <div id="navbar" class="hidden">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu([
                     'menu'            => 'footer',
                     'theme_location'  => 'footer',
                     'container'       => 'div',
                     'menu_id'         => 'footer',
                     'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav',
                     'depth'           => 2,
                     'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
                     'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
               ]);
            ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Am I missing a step here?

**Footer config in WP**:

[image]

Edit:

**Menu registration (funtions.php):**

```
public function register_menus() {
        // Register the nav menus
                register_nav_menus(
                    array(
                        'footer' => __('Footer', 'tp_theme'),
                    )
                );
    }
```

Comment: Can you also share where you create the menu with [register_nav_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) ?

Comment: Have you checked menu as a primary or other?

Comment: @janw edited my question :)

Comment: @SamirSheikh - Sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Ah, don't worry about it! Turns out my nav was hidden behind a div! thanks for your help though :)